# Java Exception

Tags: многопоточность, java

Есть класс

```
class someClass{
   public void start() throws mException{
        ...
   }

   public void cancel(){

   }
}
```

В методе start выполняется долгая операция, а в методе cancel эту операцию нужно прекратить. Как это сделать?

Comment: А при каком условии ее нужно прекратить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Напрашивается многопоточность. Какой-то булевый флаг должен проверяться в start эпизодически, например:

```
class SomeType
{
    private Object lockObj_;            // Объект блокировки
    private volatile boolean сanceled_; // Условие прерывания

    public void start()
    {
        сanceled_ = false;
        /* Создается поток, внутри которого происходит обработка задачи.
        Через некоторые промежутки проверяется условие прерывания
        (флаг canceled), если он истинный, то поток завершает свою работу
        (выходит из метода run)
        */
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (/*...*/)
                {
                    // ... Работа потока ...
                    synchronized(lockObj)
                    {
                        if (сanceled_) return;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        th.start();
    }

    public void cancel()
    {
        synchronized(lockObj)
        {
            сanceled_ = true;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В классе надо создать Handler.

```
Handler mHander = new Handler();
```

Далее создаём Runnable:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() { public void run() { /*делаем то, что надо */ } };
```

Потом в start:

```
mHandler.post(r);
```

В cancel:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(r);
```

Comment: Это из Android API? (Handler)

Answer (score 2):

Как то так (надо только адаптировать к многопоточности)

```
class SomeClass {   
  private volatile boolean check;

  public void start() throws mException {
     check=true;
     while(check) {
         //....
     }
  }

  public void cancel() {   
     check=false;
  }
}
```